# How to have QGIS open attribute tables in a new window, as opposed to opening in a new tab on MacOS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I'm a fairly new QGIS user and I recently upgraded MacBooks from 2012 MacBook Pro to 2019 MacBook Pro, and thus downloaded a slightly newer version of QGIS (3.16.15-Hannover). On my old system, it would open attribute tables in a new window, where one would be able to quickly 3 finger swipe between the attribute table window and the QGIS project window. Now attribute tables are opening in a new tab, requiring hovering the mouse at the top of the screen for a moment, waiting for the tabs bar to show up, and then clicking on the new tab to switch.

When closing the attribute table tab, it leaves a blank, black, window open.

It is not a major problem, but rather a frustrating inconvenience. I have looked for a setting within QGIS, but have only found "open new attribute tables as docked windows". Is there something I am missing, or has it arisen from the MacOS upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Toggle the *Dock Attribute Table* button on the attribute table:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the help Matt, I messed around with the MacOS settings and found a setting that addressed my issue. A setting that opened tabs as opposed to windows when in full screen.